# Magento 2.1.7 - Showing Rating on Category Page

Tags: magento-2.1, ratings

I have been trying to show the rating on the category listing page.  They show up if there is a rating, but I want rating to show even if there are no reviews (no stars).

In the list.phtml page i see:

```
<?php echo $block->getReviewsSummaryHtml($_product, $templateType, true); ?>
```

I also see the function

```
    public function aroundGetReviewsSummaryHtml(
    ListProduct $subject,
    callable $proceed,
    \Magento\Catalog\Model\Product $product,
    $templateType = false,
    $displayIfNoReviews = false)
{
    return $this->_helper->getCategoryShowReviews($subject->getMode())
        ? $proceed($product, $templateType, $displayIfNoReviews)
        : '';
}
```

I have tried a lot of things but can not get anything to show if there are no reviews.  The end of the functions has a variable `$displayIfNoReviews`, but if i set this to true, still doesn't show.

Anyone have any ideas I can try?

EDIT 1:
I have changed the summary_short file with the code below.  But its showing 0% now.  Not the ratings.

```
    <div class="product-reviews-summary short empty">
    <?php $rating = 0 ;?>
    <div class="rating-summary">
        <span class="label"><span><?php /* @escapeNotVerified */ echo __('Rating') ?>:</span></span>
        <div class="rating-result" title="<?php /* @escapeNotVerified */ echo $rating; ?>%">
            <span style="width:<?php /* @escapeNotVerified */ echo $rating; ?>%"><span><?php /* @escapeNotVerified */ echo $rating; ?>%</span></span>
        </div>
    </div>
   
    <div class="reviews-actions">
        <a class="action add" href="<?php /* @escapeNotVerified */ echo $urlForm; ?>">
            <?php /* @escapeNotVerified */ echo __('Be the first to review this product') ?>
        </a>
    </div>
</div>
```

EDIT 2:
[image: Percent]

```
    <?php
/**
 * Copyright © 2015 Magento. All rights reserved.
 * See COPYING.txt for license details.
 */

// @codingStandardsIgnoreFile

?>

<?php $url = $block->getReviewsUrl() . '#reviews'; ?>
<?php $urlForm = $block->getReviewsUrl() . '#review-form'; ?>
<?php if ($block->getReviewsCount()): ?>
    <?php $rating = $block->getRatingSummary(); ?>

       <div class="product-reviews-summary short<?php echo !$rating ? ' no-rating' : ''?>">
        <?php if ($rating):?>
            <div class="rating-summary">
                <span class="label"><span><?php /* @escapeNotVerified */ echo __('Rating') ?>:</span></span>

                <div class="rating-result__stars 111">
                    <?php
                    $half_star_id = round( (int)$rating / 20 );
                    for($i = 0; $i < 5; $i++){
                        if( $i < $half_star_id ) {
                            echo '<span class="rating-star__full"></span>';
                        }
                        if( $i == $half_star_id ) {
                            echo '<span class="rating-star__half"></span>';
                        }
                        if( $i > $half_star_id ) {
                            echo '<span class="rating-star__empty"></span>';
                        }
                    } ?>
                </div>

                <div class="rating-result__text">
                    <span style="width:<?php /* @escapeNotVerified */ echo $rating; ?>%"><span><?php /* @escapeNotVerified */ echo $rating; ?>%</span></span>
                </div>
            </div>
        <?php endif;?>
        
        <div class="reviews-actions">
            <a class="action view" href="<?php /* @escapeNotVerified */ echo $url ?>"><?php /* @escapeNotVerified */ echo $block->getReviewsCount() ?>&nbsp;<span><?php /* @escapeNotVerified */ echo($block->getReviewsCount() == 1) ? __('Review') : __('Reviews') ?></span></a>
        </div>
    </div>
<?php elseif ($block->getDisplayIfEmpty()): ?>

    <div class="product-reviews-summary short empty">
        <?php $rating = 0 ;?>
        <div class="rating-summary">
            <span class="label"><span><?php /* @escapeNotVerified */ echo __('Rating') ?>:</span></span>
            <div class="rating-result" title="<?php /* @escapeNotVerified */ echo $rating; ?>%">
                <span style="width:<?php /* @escapeNotVerified */ echo $rating; ?>%"><span><?php /* @escapeNotVerified */ echo $rating; ?>%</span></span>
            </div>
        </div>
       
        <div class="reviews-actions">
            <a class="action add" href="<?php /* @escapeNotVerified */ echo $urlForm; ?>">
                <?php /* @escapeNotVerified */ echo __('Be the first to review this product') ?>
            </a>
        </div>
    </div>
<?php else: ?>   
    <div class="testclass2"></div>
      <?php $rating = $block->getRatingSummary(); ?>
       
       <div class="product-reviews-summary short<?php echo !$rating ? ' no-rating' : ''?>">
        <?php if ($rating):?>
            <div class="rating-summary">
                <span class="label"><span><?php /* @escapeNotVerified */ echo __('Rating') ?>:</span></span>

                <div class="rating-result__stars 11">
                    <?php
                    $half_star_id = round( (int)$rating / 20 );
                    for($i = 0; $i < 5; $i++){
                        if( $i < $half_star_id ) {
                            echo '<span class="rating-star__full"></span>';
                        }
                        if( $i == $half_star_id ) {
                            echo '<span class="rating-star__half"></span>';
                        }
                        if( $i > $half_star_id ) {
                            echo '<span class="rating-star__empty"></span>';
                        }
                    } ?>
                </div>

                <div class="rating-result__text">
                    <span style="width:<?php /* @escapeNotVerified */ echo $rating; ?>%"><span><?php /* @escapeNotVerified */ echo $rating; ?>%</span></span>
                </div>
            </div>
        <?php endif;?>
        <div class="reviews-actions">
            <a class="action view" href="<?php /* @escapeNotVerified */ echo $url ?>"><?php /* @escapeNotVerified */ echo $block->getReviewsCount() ?>&nbsp;<span><?php /* @escapeNotVerified */ echo($block->getReviewsCount() == 1) ? __('Review') : __('Reviews') ?></span></a>
        </div>
    </div>
<?php endif; ?>
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want to ***show rating on those products*** which does not have any rating then you need to **`some changes at template phtml files`** also there are no need to use `aroundGetReviewsSummaryHtml`.
Also make `<?php echo $block->getReviewsSummaryHtml($_product, $templateType, true); ?>`

Comment: Thank you for the reply.  However, its showing 0% when I add the code.  I have updated my post to include your code (EDIT 1).  Anyway to get the stars?

Comment: Any chance I can get help on this still?  Its showing percent instead of stars.

Comment: The above worked, just shows the %.  I need the stars if possible.

Comment: Star should  be shown  here. Please  check  the on default  Magento

Comment: Default magento shows this empty stars on the catalog page?
I have attached a screenshot of the issue on EDIT 2.  If it has reviews, it shows stars.  If not, a percent.

Comment: Amit, and suggestions?

Comment: Please share full code of summary_short.phtml

Comment: Amit, Thanks again for helping.  I edited my post to include the code.  It formatted it weird though.